# JavaFX desktop deployment as EXE file

Tags: deployment, ant, javafx, inno-setup

I am using eclipse IDE and have been trying to deploy the application with Ant from inside Eclipse as an .EXE file. Inno Setup 5.0 is installed and in my environment path.

`C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card`

This is the Error I have from the build
Project\build\build\classes\META-INF
Using base JDK at: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre`
Bundler EXE Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

My question is how do I include the jar and do I have the path coorect for Inno Setup 5.0

Answer (score 2):

@Phantomazi
nice edit 
@James Duh

Here are the step by step instructions to build an EXE file with Eclipse Luna for a JavaFX Project

Right Click Project Name in Eclipse

Select Build Path

Configure Build Path

Click Libraries Tab

Click Add JAR

Select your project then navigate to build -> dist -> libs

You should have a ProjectName.jar file in the libs folder

If not create a jar file by opening build.fxfuild

Set Package Format to NONE

Click Generate ant build.xml and run

then set Package Format back to EXE

You Console View will tell you where the EXE file was saved
Example

C:\Users\User Name\workspace\Project Name\build\deploy\bundles

Comment: @2475470 This worked great Thank You for the step by step I am not sure why I need the JAR file but It works. It would be nice to use Inno Setup 5 and not use the build.fxbuild lets see if the Phantomazi corrects your spelling I would vote your answer up but I am only a 6th grade novice ha ha